# Setting up Package.json for Heroku deployment of Backend and Frontend Node/React Project

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, create-react-app, package.json

I have a project structured like this:

```
|
|-- frontend/
|   | ...(create-react-app)
|   | package.json
|
|-- backend/
|   | ...(node.js & express serving an API)
|   | package.json
|
| package.json
|
```

I have been struggling to fathom out how to host this on a single domain on Heroku so that both the frontend and backend API are accessible. There are a few tutorials available that suggest that one solution is to have both servers (React and Express) running at once and setup a proxy instruction for API calls.

None of these quite work for my particular setup and I have had to hack my root level package.json so that it builds, launches and installs across the assorted folders in my project.

I don't feel like my current solution is optimal and would appreciate comments on the script section of my root package.json. Can it be improved? It does seem to work with my hosted project but I feel like it could be improved by someone who understands the Heroku build process.

Root level package.json:

```
{
  "name": "paddlr",
  "description": "ping pong brilliance",
  "main": "backend/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd frontend && npm start",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm server\" \"npm client\"",
    "dev:server": "cd frontend && npm build && cd .. && npm start",
    "start": "node backend/index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd backend && npm install && cd ../frontend && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: The CRA server isn't meant for production usage. Instead you should build the React app and serve it *from* Express, see e.g. my starter project https://github.com/textbook/cyf-app-starter; it stills uses the proxy for local dev.

Comment: Thanks for the link to your repo, it looks to be just what I need! I see you don't have a package.json for your server folder in the way that I do. Also from the looks of your README you can actually test this locally. I have only been able to replicate the switching after I have hosted which seems pretty bad form. I will fork your repo today and put it to the test but I suspect it is going to be really helpful.